# How make an OverlayItem tapped by default?

Tags: android, android-maps

Basically I have a `MapView` and an `OverlayItem`. I know how to manage the `onTap` event, but I want to make that `OverlayItem` tapped by default. In other way, how to activate that listener programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you just call the onClickListener() for whichever object you want to trigger?

Comment: Yes, I should have looked more attentively... :)

Comment: :-)  I would be a great programmer if I always knew *where* to look more attentively!

Comment: how do you call an overlay items on click listener directly?

Comment: I haven't touched the code in a while, but I guess it's just your_object.onClickListener();

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should use `mapItemizedOverlayObject.onTap(indexOfOverlayItem)` method, it does not have `onClickListener()` method.